# C++ allocator to store objects of different types

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a bunch of objects wrapped by unique_ptrs. 
Each object is of its own type. 
I would like to create a kind of memory pool to store all those objects to avoid heap allocations for every last object. Like this: 

Allocator allocator(1024); // should be extendable
unique_ptr< A > a = allocator.allocateAndWrapToUPtr< A >();
unique_ptr< B > b = allocator.allocateAndWrapToUPtr< B >();
C* c = allocator.allocate< C >(); 

As far as I can see allocators are specified as
template 
class MyAllocator; 
Hence they can store only objects of only one type. 

Is it possible to implement "multitype" allocator?

Comment: What actual, specific problem does "heap allocations for every last object" create for you?

Comment: Have you not looked at something like this: http://dmitrysoshnikov.com/compilers/writing-a-pool-allocator/

Comment: Allocators are not the most trivial part of C++ and their usage is mainly hidden by higher constructs. Instead of dealing with their gory details, you could use a factory class containing vectors of them and a pseudo destructor returning the object to the pool. If you go the allocator way, you must be aware that the object allocator will be used by default for subobject allocation (strings for example).

Comment: Found it, but it is not compliant with std::allocator interface, hence I will not be able to use it inside collections for example. This is ok, just wanted to make sure I can not use one thing for my uptrs, collections and so on. Looks like the approach is like this: if you need an allocator for multiple object types - use a non-templated allocator like in the example. If you want to use an allocator for collection - use a templated one with stl compatible interface. I just thought I can allocate a huge amount of memory and use it for everything in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to use one allocator everywhere around the project. 
Dynamic allocator example can be found at dmitrysoshnikov.com/compilers/writing-a-pool-allocator, it allows to solve the initial problem with unique_ptrs. 
But it is not stl compliant so can not be used for collections for example.